# How to quickly find keys matching a pattern in an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I did something as below to find patterns in my bucket

```
def getListOfPrefixesFromS3(dataPath: String, prefix: String, delimiter: String, batchSize: Integer): List[String] = {
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client()
    var listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(dataPath).withMaxKeys(batchSize).withPrefix(prefix).withDelimiter(delimiter)
    var objectListing: ObjectListing = null
    var res: List[String] = List()

    do {
      objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
      res = res ++ objectListing.getCommonPrefixes
      listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker)
    } while (objectListing.isTruncated)
    res
  }
```

For larger buckets this consumes too much of time since all the object summaries are returned by the Aws and not only the ones that match the prefix and the delimiter. I am looking for ways to improve the performance and so far i've only found that i should name the keys and organise them in buckets properly.

It would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction, or provide me a hint, howsoever small it may be it would be very nice.

I am using java sdk for AWS and this code runs inside a spark job, which is mostly in scala.

Edit 1 : Because i am using spark. What i have started to do is find the keys with delimiters as "/". This gives me a lot of common prefixes or say top level folders. I then use,

```
sc.parallelize(keys).map(key => getListOfPrefixesForKey(key))
```

to get list of all keys. I hope with adequate parallelisation, this will speed up search for the keys for me. As i can't move the data or reorganise it, i think it's my only way.

Can anyone add to how can i use spark more effectively to find the keys?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all the object summaries are returned by the Aws and not only the ones that match the prefix and the delimiter".  If you're providing a prefix, AWS will only return keys that match that prefix.  This is the only filtering that the S3 provides on list operations.  Show an example of what keys your bucket has and how you're calling your code.

Comment: So, what i meant was it does not match the delimiter along with the prefixes, it only matches the prefixes, gets all the keys and then in the common prefixes you get the common ones using the limited by the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 does not offer a random-access key lookup capability -- unless your object keys have semantic meaning and can be located by prefix, there is no built-in feature to allow indexed searching.

Many AWS services focus on their core competency and do not offer capabilities that overlap substantially with the features available from different AWS services.  This is an example of that.

> A common solution is to build an external index that maps queryable attributes to the S3 object key.

That's a quote from an [official AWS Blog Post](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2YRX3Y16CVQFZ/Building-and-Maintaining-an-Amazon-S3-Metadata-Index-without-Servers) addressing exactly this topic.

> This index can leverage data repositories that are built for fast lookups but might not be great at storing large data blobs.

By way of example: in my environment, one of the solutions I use for exactly this purpose is MariaDB on RDS, which maintains an index of all the keys in the monitored buckets -- and all the object versions, for versioned buckets -- as well as all of the object attributes (size, date, etag) and metadata, which is indexed and searchable as well.  The database is automatically updated by S3 events, which go in to an SQS queue, where they're processed.

But I'm not saying that this is The One True Way™.

There isn't a single right way -- there are a number of technologies that are an excellent fit for this application.  The S3 event notification functionality allows automatic near-real-time maintenance of the index, and the code that maintains the index can run in EC2 or can run serverless, using Lambda.

The blog post linked above explains how to do this with DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your very nice answer. Great use of Sqs by the way, i think we now have scheduled lambdas. Maybe we can use them also to process these events. Thanks again.